# Kdb q negative numbers and mod

Tags: kdb

Basic questions about negative numbers and mod in Kdb

Below gives -1 as expected

q) neg 7 mod 2

but

q) a:neg 7

q) a mod 2

gives 1

And below

q) -7 mod 2

gives 1

Anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 4):

KDB execute statements from right to left. So statement `neg 7 mod 2` is same as `neg(7 mod 2)`.

First KDB executes `7 mod 2` and then apply `neg` function on the result like below.

```
q) 7 mod 2 // 1
q) neg 1 // -1
```

which is same as

```
q) neg 7 mod 2 // -1
```

Last 2 cases `-7 mod 2` and `neg[7] mod 2` are equivalent. And the result for that is 1.

Comment: Does positive result by mod operator on negative domain values is again attributed to q's right to left eval? or any other reason?

Comment: Modulus is calculated by Euclidean division(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It can result in both positive and negative number. Number theory for example uses only positive modulus and define it as -> `m mod n` will be a positive number between 0 and n-1.  Different programming languages support different implementations of it. Some support both positive and negative modulus. KDB adheres to positive modulus like number theory.  You can also see how `mod` is implemented to support this - `k){x-y*x div y}`

Comment: In  arithmetic modulo, a  number is represented as 'nq+r', where r is non negative number which is the mod.  For example: -7 mod 2 will be same as (2 X -4) +1 and hence 1 is mod.

Answer (score 2):

The mod function, as shown in the kx reference page(https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/mod/), only returns positive values. Therefore, 1 is the expect answer for `-7 mod 2`, and `a mod 2` in your example.

The reason that neg 7 mod 2 returns -1 is that q evaluates arithmetic from right to left.

As `7 mod 2` return `1`, the neg function returns `-1` after taking in the value from `7 mod 2`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, q doesn't seems to be just returning positive part. For eq: "-5 mod 3" is giving out 1 not 2. Above documentation is not clear to me on this. In Java and C++ "-5 % 3" is giving out -2 where as in kdb q I expect result as "2" if it just returns positive part.

Comment: Hi @sigirisetti, -5 mod 3 gives 1 instead of 2 because it is saying that -5 is 1 more than a multiple of 3, which is true (-5 is -6 +1). It does only return positive values. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As Rahul has covered, this is expected behaviour that occurs as a result of the `right to left` execution of KDB, in conjunction with the fact that `mod` will always return a positive result in kdb. If you want to better understand how the execution of a given command is being implemented you can always parse it out, which will show the underly `k` parse tree.

```
q)mod
k){x-y*x div y}
q)neg
-:
q)parse "neg 7 mod 2"
-:
(k){x-y*x div y};7;2)
```

Here we can see that neg (`-:`) is being applied to the result of the mod (`k){x-y*x div y}`) of 7 and 2.

Right to left trips up many that are learning kdb. It will be useful to keep this aspect in mind as a possible cause for *any* problem that you encounter with kdb as you learn the basics, I can guarantee that it will trip you up at least a few more times.

I'd really recommend that you read/work through Q For Mortals 3, which has been made free by [Kx](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/)